# Is it a good idea to ask my Master's supervisor to help me finding a PhD in other universities?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor

I am in final stages of my Master degree in physics. I am looking for a PhD position in Europe. Is it a good idea to ask my supervisor to help in me finding a position for PhD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it would be a very good idea to ask your supervisor. They know the field much better than you do. They likely have contacts in many places and also know which universities would be a good match for your interests. Many places will want a recommendation from your supervisor anyways, so it would be good to have them on board.

I would not phrase the request as "Please help me find a PhD position" but more casually, for example: "I am interested in doing a PhD, do you happen to know of any openings?".

Comment: Agree except for the last line. I would be more direct/ask for more specific types of help. In other words “what universities or research groups would be a good match for my interest?” “Can you help me strategize about the best way to reach out?”

Comment: @Dawn Thank you. I think it will be a better to ask for direct help, as you are saying.